# How to console.log an item inside a v-for loop in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I can't figure out how to do a `console.log` to see what item is in the `ul` as its being passed.

```
 <div v-for="(item, index) in todos" :key="index">
     <ul v-if="item" :load="console.log(item)">
         <li v-for="(value, key) in item" :key="key">
            <label v-bind:for="key">{{ key }}</label>
            <div v-bind:id="key">{{ value }}</div>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#components-demo',
    data: {
        todos: [
            newData
        ]
    }
 })
```

Comment: it should just display, you should just look at what HTML the template is outputting, I think console logging would be a bit of overkill here

Comment: i guess i need for future endeavors as well, i need to know how to do it

Comment: a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080447/how-can-i-use-console-log-or-console-error-in-a-vue-template

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you should define a method like :

```
  <ul v-if="item" :load="log(item)">
```

in your script  :

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#components-demo',
  data: {
    todos: [
      newData
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    log(item) {
      console.log(item)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: to use globally, add `Vue.prototype.log = console.log;` in `main.js`

Answer (score 7):

I usually wrap the value I'm debugging in `<pre>{{ myData }}</pre>` like this:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in todos" :key="index">
     <pre>{{ item }}</pre>
     <ul v-if="item" :load="item">
         <li v-for="(value, key) in item" :key="key">
            <label v-bind:for="key">{{ key }}</label>
            <div v-bind:id="key">{{ value }}</div>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

But you can also use console if you pass it into t he template context during create

```
 <div v-for="(item, index) in todos" :key="index">
     <ul v-if="item" :load="console.log(item)">
         <li v-for="(value, key) in item" :key="key">
            <label v-bind:for="key">{{ key }}</label>
            <div v-bind:id="key">{{ value }}</div>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#components-demo',
    data: {
        todos: [
            newData
        ]
    },
    created() {
      this.console = window.console;
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Daniel's answer, but you can simply reference `console` in data object

```
data(){
  return {
  console, //ES6
  ...
  }
}
```