# Why is "console" not defined in an inline function that handles an event from a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, console.log, arrow-functions

I wrote a component `my-component` that emits the message `my-message` via `this.$emit('my-message')`.

In order to act on this message, I tried to use

```
<my-component @my-message="()=>console.log('hello')" />
```

When looking at the console, I see the warning (and then error)

```
Property or method "console" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render
```

Having made the mistake many times, I presume that the error comes from the context using fat arrows (`this` vs `that = this` before) but here I am lost.

[`console`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) is exposed as `Window.console` but `Window` generates the same error if I use the full form.

Comment: Sounds like the code is interpreting `() => console.log('hello')` as trying to call `instance.console.log('hello')` then failing because `console` is not a property on the instance.

Comment: @VLAZ: thanks, that was my supposition as well. But in that case how can I call it via the `Window` object?

Comment: Dunno. I'm not sure what and why is taking that function and how it's used. Presumably `() => window.console` will be resolved as `instance.window.console`. If so, you can probably try a hack like `() => (void, console.log("hello"))` and hope it's not interpreted weirdly. Or try further syntax hacks. Although, it's probably better to get to the bottom of why this happens. Hopefully somebody comes here with an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will not work in Vue.

Pass a method name instead

```js
<template>
  <button @click="log('test')">
    test
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  methods: {
    log(value) {
      console.log(value)
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks - this is how I do it normally, but I wanted to avoid adding a method. If there is no other way I will go for that

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could place the global objects to a computed:

```
computed: {
  console: () => console,
  window: () => window,
}
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60240938/7889584) from @tao

##### OR

You can define them as global **properties**.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68688746/7889584) from @[wenfang-du](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7881859/wenfang-du):