# Why is bootstrap-vue not rendering onclick?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a bootstrap-vue b-button with a v-on:click tag.  But the rendered HTML does not contain the onclick event.  Here are the dependencies:

```
"webpack": "^5.35.1",
"webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
"vue": "^2.6.12",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
```

The button:

```
<b-button :disabled="document.status==='Complete' || document.status==='Canceled'"
                    variant="primary"
                    title="Resend"
                    v-on:click="console.log('click')"
                >
```

The rendered HTML:

```
<button title="Resend" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">...</button>
```

As seen above, the onclick is not rendered in the HTML.  Why am I not getting my onclick?

Comment: I dont think you have access to the console object at that time..
Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080447/how-can-i-use-console-error-or-console-log-in-a-vue-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-on:` (or just `@`) will create event listener, so it won't be visible in html anyway.

`console` refering to nothing (it's undefined, check your web console) while you doing it in html, inline. You can use global `this`, then it should work (`this.console.log(...)`).

Even better practice, try this:

```
<b-button :disabled="document.status==='Complete' || document.status==='Canceled'"
                    variant="primary"
                    title="Resend"
                    v-on:click="clickHandler"
                >
```

then in methods:

```
clickHandler() { console.log('clicked') }
```

Comment: Thank you.  Did not realize about the HTML render.  Even when I move the clickHandler to the methods portion of the class it still does not fire.  I suppose I asked the wrong question.  The event does not fire, no matter how I attempt to do the v-on:click code.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you have production mode enabled in your webpack configuration file? If not, check configuration files for something like `no-console`.

Comment: '"watch": "webpack --watch --mode=development"'  is how I am running.  Do not have 'no-console' anywhere.

Comment: Is browser console says anything while you firing an event?

Comment: Well, it was my build going south.  It works with your answer.