# how to use Arrow function in a inline event handler

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have this component (vue3+ts)

```
 <q-input type="number" filled model-value="Model.Code" @update:model-value="val=>console.log(val)" />
```

i don't understand why I'm getting this error message :

```
Property 'console' does not exist on type '({ $:
ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{ [x: number]:
string; } | {}> & Omit<(readonly string[] | Readonly<{ [x: string]:
unknown; } & {} & { [x: string]: Prop<...> | ... 1 more ... |
undefined; }>) & (VNodeProps & ... 2 more ... & Readonly<...>),
never>; ... 10 more ...; $watch(source: string |...'.
```

what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60240938/8816585)?

Comment: @kissu i did , this.console.log gives the error ( object is possible undefined ) and this?console.log gives ( property console does not exist on type never )

Comment: Alright, the rest is how to type a `console.log` properly so. I don't know TS, cannot help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console` doesn't exist inside `<template>`.

To `log` something you need to create a method inside the `<script>`. For example:

```html
<template>
  <q-input type="number" filled model-value="Model.Code" @update:model-value="clg" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const clg = (item: any) => {
      console.log(item);
    };

    return { clg };
  },
});
</script>
```