# VueJS: copy tag content to clipboard at click without creating function

Tags: vue.js

How to copy the content of an html tag to clipboard without using own function?

```
<div @click="navigator.clipboard.writeText(this)">Hello {{ name }}!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [`document`](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#access-to-platform-specific-apis), Universal code cannot assume access to platform-specific APIs, so if your code directly uses browser-only globals like `window` or `document`, they will throw errors. Hence, the common approach is to lazily access them inside client-only lifecycle hooks such as `mounted`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Alpha',
    browserApi: null
  },
  mounted() {
    this.browserApi = navigator
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div ref="elText" @click="browserApi.clipboard.writeText($refs.elText.innerText)">Hello {{ name }}!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in Vue3 that is not possible without 'ugly' solutions, [see here for inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080447/how-can-i-use-console-log-or-console-error-in-a-vue-template/68688746#68688746). But I think the cleanest way is to just create a method with that one line of code in it.

Answer (score 0):

better for readability

Vue;

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Alpha',
  },
  methods {
    copyPageUrl(){
        navigator.clipboard.writeText($refs.elText.innerText)
    },
  }
})
```

Html;

```
<div id="app">
  <div ref="elText" @click="copyPageUrl">Hello {{ name }}!</div>
</div>
```