# Nuxt3 Button doesn't register @click event

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have the simplest nuxt3 project and my button when pressed doesn't register a click event.

Why?
Or where can I look for a solution?

`<button @click="console.log('PRESSED')" class="bg-gray-500">GENERATE TEXT</button>`

.
Replication:

1. `npx nuxi init replica_project`
2. `cd replica_project`
3. `npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/tailwindcss`
4. Added in `nuxt.config.ts` `modules: [    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'  ]`
5. Put `<button @click="console.log('I got hit on')" class="bg-gray-500">HIT ME BABY</button>` in the `App.vue` file
   `

---

Tried Solutions:

1. Add `.native`: `<button @click.native="console.log('PRESSED')" class="bg-gray-500">GENERATE TEXT</button>`

Comment: Any errors in the console? Try to use it via a method. `console.log` needs to be declared actually.

Comment: @kissu No errors. I pressed the button and the console didn't react. However I updated my machine, turned it off and tried again today.... Now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my machine, turned it off, tried again today and it worked.

I have no further explanation...

Comment: Should not work tho. Check if you have any errors in your console.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way of using a `console.log` is by using a function to call it (rather than doing it directly from the template), like the following.
Using the CompositionAPI:

```html
<script setup>
function consoleHitOn() {
  console.log('I got hit on')
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="consoleHitOn">HIT ME BABY</button>
</template>
```

Using the OptionsAPI, you could achieve the same [with a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60240938/8816585) by doing this

```html
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    console: () => console,
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="console.log('I got hit on')">HIT ME BABY</button>
</template>
```

I'm not sure if there is a way of writing the same kind of hack with CompositionAPI, but even if there is I do not really recommend it anyway.

---

PS: one thing for sure is that it's **totally** not related to TailwindCSS.
Tailwind is for the style, nothing concerning the event listeners in a Vue app.

Answer (score 1):

Below command fixed issue at my end.
just **npm run build** when its build successfully do **npm run dev** it might fix your issue it worked at my end,

when I run build I found few issues, fixed them and run again dev